# How do I output multiple values(discounts)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to understand how to return multiple values. Right now my code is set up to return a single object(redeemDisc) for any code that has exactly one redemption code. My problem is that if a code has more than one redemption code it just returns 'multiple discounts'. I am trying to understand how to store 'redeemDisc' in an array so that if there are multiple discounts I can just return all of them

```
redeemCode({ userUuid, code }) {
let error;
let locationId;
return this.models.BusinessLocation.findOne({
  where: {
    code: code,
    deleted: false
  }
}).then(loc => {

  if (loc === null)
  {
    error = 'Invalid Code';
    return;
  }
  locationId = loc.id;
  return this.models.OfferLocation.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
      locationId: loc.id
    }
  })
}).then(async offerLocs => {

    if (offerLocs.length === 0)
    {
      return "Zero Discounts";
    }
    let count = 0;
    let offer;
    let i;
    for ( i = 0; i < offerLocs.rows.length;i++)
    {
        let offerLoc = offerLocs.rows[i];
        offer = await this.models.Discount.findOne({
          where: {
            id: offerLoc.offerId
          }
        });

        if (!offer.active || offer.deleted)
        {
          continue;
        }

        count++;
    }

    console.log('redeeemCode -service (offer count)', count) ;       
    console.log('redeeemCode -service (offer )', JSON.stringify(offer)) ;       

    if (count > 1)
    {
      return 'multiple discounts';
    }
    if (count === 0)
    {
      return 'zero discounts';
    }

    // have a single offer - claim

    return this.redeemDisc(
      { discountId: offer.id , 
        userUuid: userUuid, 
        code: code, 
        locationId: locationId
      }).then(redeemed => {
        return redeemed;
        }
        )


})
```

}

For a single discount it returns JSON in the form of

```
"redeemed": {
    "createdAt": "2019-10-27T23:54:14.031Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-10-27T23:54:14.031Z",
    "id": "143751f0-f915-11e9-8107-658322eb948c",
    "UserUuid": "b136ccd9-0783-482d-956b-7082286051b3",
    "DiscountId": "97cfdf90-3ee0-11e9-b720-c1f2606cbbd2",
    "BusinessId": "978a7220-3ee0-11e9-b720-c1f2606cbbd2",
    "locationId": "97cf1c40-3ee0-11e9-b720-c1f2606cbbd2"
}
```

I need to understand how to return all discounts associated with a given code, so the expected output would be

redeemed: { ... },
redeemed: { ... },
...

Comment: Clean indentation, remove useless parts like `.then(redeemed => { return redeemed;})`, learn how to use Promise to avoid things like `error = 'Invalid Code'; return;` that will completly  crashes on line `offerLocs.length`, do not used semi global variable like error or locationId, .... It's easier to clean / debug a clear code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are having multiple offers related to one code then you have to use array of offers instead of variable and you should store every detail of offer in that offer array.

```
let offer = [];
let i;
for ( i = 0; i < offerLocs.rows.length;i++)
{
    let offerLoc = offerLocs.rows[i];
    offer[count] = await this.models.Discount.findOne({
      where: {
        id: offerLoc.offerId
      }
    });

    if (!offer.active || offer.deleted)
    {
      continue;
    }

    count++;
}
```

And now you can store and return the discount array like this.

```
var discount = []
for(let j =0; j<offer.length; ++j) {
   let redeem = await this.redeemDisc(
                  { discountId: offer.id , 
                    userUuid: userUuid, 
                    code: code, 
                    locationId: locationId
                  })
  discount.push({"redeemed": redeem})                 

}

return discount;
```